# How to read variables from a file decrypted at build time using Google Cloud Build and Google Cloud KMS

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-kms

I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#encrypting_an_environment_variable_using_the_cryptokey) tutorial for getting encrypted keys into my cloudbuild YAML file.
I am trying to understand how am I supposed to " use the decrypted ... file in the workspace directory" variables in the subsequent steps of my YAML file.

My cloudbuild step where I decrypt the keys file is as follows:

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['kms', 'decrypt', '--ciphertext-file=<encrypted_file>', '--plaintext-file=<decrypted_file>', '--location=<location>', '--keyring=<keyring>', '--key=<key>']
```

The tutorial is not clear on how to do this and I cannot find anything on the Internet related to this.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you encrypt your content with `gcloud kms encrypt`, you can write the output to a file in your workspace, for example:

```
# replace with your values
gcloud kms encrypt \
  --location=global \
  --keyring=my-kr \
  --key=my-key \
  --plaintext-file=./data-to-encrypt \
  --ciphertext-file=./encrypted-data
```

Where `./data-to-encrypt` is a file on disk that contains your *plaintext* secret and `./encrypted-data` is the destination path on disk where the encrypted *ciphertext* should be written.

When working directly with the API, the interaction looks like this:

```
plaintext -> kms(encrypt) -> ciphertext
```

However, when working with `gcloud`, it looks like this:

```
plaintext-file -> gcloud(read) -> kms(encrypt) -> ciphertext -> gcloud(write)
```

When you invoke Cloud Build, it effectively gets a tarball of your application, minus any files specified in a `.gcloudignore`. That means `./encrypted-data` will be available on the filesystem inside the container step:

```
steps:
# decrypt the value in ./my-secret
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args:
  - kms
  - decrypt
  - --location=global
  - --keyring=my-kr
  - --key=my-key
  - --ciphertext=file=./encrypted-data
  - --plaintext-file=./my-secret

- name: gcr.io/my-project/my-image
  steps: 
  - my-app start --secret=./my-secret
```

At present, the only way to share data between steps in Cloud Build is with files, but all build steps have the same shared filesystem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. 
As a last step, after building the image, I am deploying to a Cloud Run service.
How could I pass the my-secret file to the service? As an example, assuming the deciphered file was a json, how could I pass that json as a, for instance, environment variable with --set-env-vars?

Comment: You would need to make sure you're on a base image with bash and unix tools and `cat` the contents of the file into the flag. However, note that environment variables are _not_ considered part of a threat model for Cloud Run. Anyone with project/viewer or higher permissions can see environment variables in the web ui. It's also very easy to leak plaintext environment variables. See https://www.sethvargo.com/secrets-in-serverless and check out https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/berglas for more secure alternatives.

Comment: And would it be possible to pass, as environment variable, the path to the file (is this even possible?!) and then load the file in the code? As an alternative to the solutions you proposed.

Comment: You can pass environment variables, but they don't persist between steps. The only thing shared between steps is the filesystem.

Comment: Sethvargo, thank you again for your support. 
I have followed the post you linked you your previous comment and everything is now working as expected. I will mark your answer as accepted. 
Thanks again!

Comment: One of my colleagues just published this today, which illustrates how to share (larger) volumes of data among GCB steps: https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-pass-data-between-cloud-build-steps-de5c9ebc4cdd